# Xpath for item with same attribute value as ancestor

Tags: java, xml, xpath, substitution, pmd

How would I write an xpath query to match the `<subitem>` element in the XML snippet below?

Specifically I want to match any element that has a "name" attribute that matches the value of the "name" attribute of the root. There may be an arbitrary number of ancestors between `<root>` and `<subitem>`.

```
<root name="xyz">
  <anything>
    <subitem name="xyz" />
  </anything>
</root>
```

My goal is to write a PMD rule for finding cases of Logger.getLogger() that use a different class than the class the statement is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
//*[@name = /*/@name]
```

This selects any element (including the top element named `root`), whose `name` attribute has the same string value as that of the `name` attribute of the top element. When this XPath expression is evaluated against the provided XML document, two elements -- `root` and `subitem` are selected.

**I think that only the second element of these two is wanted. For this, use the following XPath expression**:

```
//*/*[@name = /*/@name]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="//*/*[@name = /*/@name]"/>
========
   <xsl:copy-of select="//*[@name = /*/@name]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root name="xyz">
    <anything>
        <subitem name="xyz" />
    </anything>
</root>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<subitem name="xyz"/>
========
   <root name="xyz">
    <anything>
      <subitem name="xyz"/>
    </anything>
   </root>
   <subitem name="xyz"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`//*[@name=(ancestor::*/@name)]`

This should do the trick. I would read it as "Find all nodes that have an ancestor with the same `name`."

---

**EDIT** (plus a second one, it still selected too much)

After the edit of the question:

`//*[@name=(/@name)]`

This reads as "Find all nodes that have the same `name` as the root node." Note that the root node might not be what you think it to be (and you want to match against the topmost node named `root`, not [root](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node)), and you might need to implement it as

`//*[@name=(/root/@name)]` or `//*[@name=(/*/@name)]`

---

This selects two elements, your `subitem` and `root` which is not wanted, you only want to select nodes that are *not topmost* (are descendants of `root`). Credits to Dimitre Novatchev for this.

`//*/*[@name=(/*/@name)]`

Comment: Oh, you edited the question, now this query would find more that you want. Gonna edit.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Really? I'm seriously interested in this as I use internal IntelliJ XPath support and/or [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to evaluate my XPath expressions and none of those reported any warnings or errors. It would be great to have a tool to validate my expressions and point out my syntactical mistakes.

Comment: @Slanec: OK, a small correction -- the last two of the three expressions. Actually their syntax is OK, but they don't select any node. The reason is that the document (or roor) node `/` cannot have any attributes, and `/@*` selects nothing. As for a decent XPath learning tool, I can recommend (shamelessly) my own XPath Visualizer: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Comment: This is a replacement of my previous comment which stated that all expressions in this answer are syntactically illegal. All are syntactically legal, and the last two of the three aren't selecting any node.